What is the statistical model for an Ordinal outcome variable predicted with binary, ordinal, continuous and nominal predictors?
I have paired survey data of healthcare workers (HCWs) taken pre- and post-COVID-19 pandemic. The purpose is twofold: (1) To determine HCW Job Satisfaction (JS) and HCW Intention-to-Leave (ITL) pre-pandemic (circa 2018) and (2) to Measure changes in JS and ITL due to the pandemic once the lockdowns were lifted (circa 2021).
JS is a 4-point Likert scale variable (Strongly Disagree, Disagree, Agree, Strong Agree). ITL is a 5-point Likert scale variable (Strongly Disagree, Disagree, Neutral, Agree, Strong Agree). About 110 predictors for each dependent variable are binary, ordinal, nominal, and continuous variables. Let's assume the number of predictors has been reduced (if it matters) by elimination through identifying collinearity issues.
The analysis will be done in SAS, but I don't need that code now. I need to understand the nature of the regressions I need to perform. I know multinomial regression is not the way to go (unless the regression(s) model is (are) a poor fit for the data). Let's assume we generate good models to fit the data perfectly.
What should the pre-pandemic regression model equation look like? Will it be:

p(x)_JS = 1 / (1 + exp-(b0 + b1x1 + b2x2 ... + bn*xn), where p(x)_JS is the JS model representation, a cumulative probability distribution function that sums to 1.0 and bn and xn are the nth regression coefficient and predictors respectively.

p(x)_JS / (1 - p(x)_JS) = exp-(b0 + b1x1 + b2x2 ... + bn*xn. I realize this is a rewrite of #1.


Are the above equations valid even though x predictors are multi-variable types (binary's, ordinals, nominals and continuous) types?  If so, how would the model equations differ when computing the "Change_in_JS_due_to_Pandemic" model?
Thanks,
David

See https://fharrell.com/post/rpo

Thank you, @frank-harrell, for your answer, but for the past couple of days, I've failed to relate your answer in the posted link to my question. Would it be possible to answer my question directly? Thank you!

I was alluding to using ordinal regression if Y is ordinal.

Ok, so the equations I listed for the log odds are correct. Similar to what you linked.
